# How can I have a variable be changed throughout multiple Python modules?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, scope

I've been stuck on trying to get this to work for hours now. I'm very inexperienced with programming, so I'm sorry if what I'm trying to do is completely ridiculous. If at all possible, I would like to avoid creating .txt,.config, or .JSON (or any other file that isn't .py) file to keep variables for simplicity's sake.

I want my program to have an 'experience' variable. Throughout my game, I would like to be able to add onto this variable at any given instance in the game in multiple different files. (There are around 10 other variables that I would also like the program to be able to use throughout multiple modules). I'm sorry if you've seen me ask a very similar question today. But I feel like I'm getting so close to solving this error and then it ends up not working. I'm so close!

```
#File1.py
experience = 0
from File2 import givexp
class game:
    def give_xp(self,given_xp):
        global experience
        experience += given_xp
        print('Experience: ',experience)
player = game()
def main():
    print('1) give xp')
    print('2) give 500 xp')
    donow = input()
    if donow == '1':
        givexp() #this is in File2.py
    if donow == '2':
        player.give_xp(500)
while 1:
    main()
```

```
#File2.py
def givexp():
    from main import player
    player.give_xp(200)
```

Right now the only issue this is giving me is when I press 1 the first time the program asks me what to do, nothing happens and it asks me what to do again. I think this is because of the import statement in File2. So when I add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        main()
```

this completely messes up the program and now the two files will have their own experience variable, which I cannot comprehend. 
I'm aware that I can change my class to a regular function and have the experience be returned, but in my actual game, there are going to be a lot more variables to keep track of, and I would like to do it other ways than having "var1, var2, var3, etc = part_one_of_game()

Everything right now with this code works exactly the way I want it to, except for that pesky bug where the game asks the player what he or she wants to do twice the first time it is run. Is there a simple fix to this?

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: I'm baffled by it to. When it is there, the program does not go through the "what do you want to do" stage twice, but File1 and File2 will have two completely separate variables for experience. Without the "if __name__...." condition, I can keep adding experience (without going to File2), but the second I press '1' (goes to File2), my experience resets to 0. However, the experience variable is the same for both File1 and File2, which is what I am trying to get.

Comment: @KyleMe If you're looking to store the values cross-sessions, check shadows solution. If you don't care at all about that check Olegs solution. But from my understanding you're looking into how to save 10 variables between "reboots" (sessions), and if so [pickle.load()](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html#examples) is your poison, either that or a SQLite database (or even a proper database). **note:** pickle can `.dump()` class objects too in newer versions, so store all 10 values in a class, dump the class and you're done.

Comment: @Torxed Awesome. I will keep that in mind. When I would (eventually get around to making) a save file for the game, I was most likely going to use the method of saving each individual variable and then loading it up using a different module. That sounds much simpler. However, I need to just need to get the functionality of the game before the save file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think cyclic import is not good idea because this cause layering issue.

it's better to move `game` class out of `__main__` module

as for your question consider to use `game` properties to store variables to keep track  of

```
# game.py
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.experience = 0
    def give_xp(self,given_xp):
        self.experience += given_xp
        print('Experience: ',experience)

#File2.py
def givexp(player):
    player.give_xp(200)

#File1.py
from game import Game
player = Game()
def main():
    print('1) give xp')
    print('2) give 500 xp')
    donow = input()
    if donow == '1':
        givexp(player) #this is in File2.py
    if donow == '2':
        player.give_xp(500)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        main()
```

Comment: Note: This does not store the values between sessions.

Comment: can't see where this was asked?

Comment: *"OP didn't ask to get shot in the foot, doesn't mean we should give him the code to do so."*, - Quote from all my received downvotes when giving just enough to solve the problem at hand. You're right, the code above would solve the problem, an even better one would be to instruct the OP how to save them as well considering it's game variables and those are meant to be saved (they're usually what determines progress and 99% of games save sessions in order to continue later on). You downvoted a solution that would work al tho not precisely what the OP asked for which i think is wrong.

Comment: Oleg is correct, I am just trying to switch them through modules. I am currently trying your code out, Oleg, and I think you may have been the first one to answer my question (FINALLY!). I greatly appreciate it. I'm just working on fixing up the code to where I don't get any errors. (I just copy-pasted your code)

Comment: @Torxed Although having a save feature is nice, that is a bit beyond my abilities at the moment. Although I appreciate Shadow's suggestion, it is just a bit too complicated for me to understand how it works, (although, I'm sure it does work).

Comment: @Torxed sorry I have not caught You. I think Question has nothing to do with serialization and saving data.

Comment: @KyleMe It's a memory dump, in short: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/ba0fd5b0dc1eae82cea6

Comment: @oleg Your answer is definitely on the right track. I'm just having some trouble. I keep getting the error "'Game' object has no attribute "experience". I've been trying to fix it, but I'm not very good with classes. I thought having the experience variable defined in __init__ would allow it to be used throughout the class. The program gets stuck on "self.experience += given_xp"

Comment: @KyleMe sorry lost `self` in `__init__` method

Comment: @oleg Well.. You have solved my question. I can't thank you enough. I have been stuck on this for a very long time now. I should really learn classes if I wasn't able to solve that simple part that you left out, haha :D. Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's `one.py`:

```
from game import gamehandle
from two import givexp
def main():
    print('1) give xp')
    print('2) give 500 xp')
    print('3) Show current XP')
    donow = input()
    if donow == '1':
        givexp(200) #this calls the function in two.py
    elif donow == '2':
        gamehandle.give_xp(500)
    elif donow == '3':
        print(gamehandle.experience)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        main()
```

And here's `two.py`:

```
from game import gamehandle
def givexp(ammount):
    gamehandle.load_variables()
    gamehandle.give_xp(ammount)
```

And finally, `game.py`:

```
import pickle
from os.path import isfile
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.experience = 0
        self.health = 0
        self.loadedFromDisk = False
    def give_xp(self, given_xp):
        self.experience += given_xp
    def save_variables(self):
        with open('game.dump', 'wb') as fh:
            pickle.dump({'xp' : self.experience, 'hp' : self.health}, fh)
    def load_variables(self):
        if not self.loadedFromDisk:
            if isfile('game.dump'):
                with open('game.dump', 'rb') as fh:
                    data = pickle.load(fh)
                    self.experience = data['xp']
                    self.hp = data['hp']
            self.loadedFromDisk = True

gamehandle = Game()
```

Start the game by calling `python3 one.py`.
The naming convention of the files are shitty, i gotta say.. But it works.

Here you can directly modify the game variable via `gamehandle` which is a global instance of the `Game()` class, and it's accessible throughout the files that have imported `from game import gamehandle`. You can also save and load variables "on the fly" by calling:

```
gamehandle.save_variables()
```

and

```
gamehandle.load_variables()
```

This syntax works and is tested compared to the other examples given...
I'd also say this is a better way of accessing the `Game` instance since instead of passing it around, you can simply do `from game import gamehandle` in order to access it which makes things a LOT easier and keeping track of the instance is a breeze compared to, let say passing it through 5 nested functions.

And as a final note, consider changing the `self.experience` to a dictionary from the start to save both time and work because eventually you'll probably want to access variables by string and doing so is going to be a lot cleaner with a dictionary.

Comment: Great answer! You've combined both data storage and classes, and provided the final source code.

Comment: @shadow Yepp, so i gave you a +1 for contributing to the idea.

Comment: I've given you a +1 as well - I like your neat implementation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) for this.

Usage:

```
import pickle

# to save variable state
with open('state.pickle', 'w+') as f:
    pickle.dump([x, y, z], f)

# to load variable state
with open('state.pickle', 'r') as f:
    x, y, z = pickle.load(f)
```

where - x, y, z - are the variables you want to save/load.

Comment: I can't see where Kyle Me ask about save/load procedure. This doesn't answer question.

Comment: @oleg - The first two paras of the Q ask about ways to use the value of a variable throughout a program, which spans multiple files. Saving/loading variable state is an easy way to achieve this. Also, the Q asks for ways to change a variable's value accordingly throughout runtime. However, I do acknowledge that the last para of the Q asks a completely different Q. Maybe OP should clarify the Q?

Comment: @oleg: OP wrote: `"py) file to keep variables for simplicity's sake."`, he wanted to avoid a .config file or json file.. That i understand because it's a hassle to parse (sort of, or at least the OP experiences it like so). However, a pickle file is exactly what the OP needs, a memory "dump" that can be easily modified and stored.

Comment: no he just want to share data inside his program between modules. Just use the same instance to operate with from different method/function and he doesn't want to use files on disk to communicate through it.

Comment: @oleg Seeing how all variables in Python are globally accessed and he's even mentioning .config and .json files i'd say he want to store them eventually.. And as people have downvoted me for numerous of times: "The OP didn't ask how to get shot in the foot that doesn't mean we should give him the code to do so", pickle is a good approach for game variables, storing them in a class is a good ground rule, combining the two give the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, exposes an important 'Gotcha'.  Each module has its own namespace. Even when you import file 2 the namespace comes *intact* and *isolated*. This isolation is good because you can have, say, functions in the two modules with the same name.  And this is the issue here: you have imported File 2 which still looks in its own namespace for variables. The error shows us this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File1.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "File1.py", line 15, in main
    givexp() #this is in File2.py
  File "/home/pi/File2.py", line 3, in givexp
    player.give_xp(200)
NameError: global name 'player' is not defined
```

You can use the lovely `global` keyword to get round this. But hey, you are on the right track with classes, so just make sure that the function from module 2 works on your instance, in this case `player` i.e. pass `player` to the function:

```
givexp(player)
```

and change File2 so that your function accepts objects:

```
#File2.py                                                                       
def givexp(obj):
    obj.give_xp(200)
```